# Reference/Documentation for javascript equivalent functions for Metro Apps?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I'm new to developing Metro apps, but I've had experience with javascript and some of its libs like Backbone, _, $, etc.  Anyhow, I've simply imported some of my js code into my new metro app and noticed that some js functions don't transfer over. The first one I've noticed was alert.  Eventually through searching, I found out that alert could be represented as

```
window.alert = function (msg) {
    var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(msg, "Alert");
    dialog.showAsync();
}
```

Another function that was weird was document.write, went I "alerted" it, it was defined, however, when I used it, my app crashed.

Anyhow, I was wondering if there is any documentation containing js functions like this that don't really map exactly to metro apps and maybe their metro equivalent, or even maybe a js lib that helps deal with this?

Also, if anyone could figure out what went wrong with my document.write() call (or maybe it worked for you?), that would be awesome, too!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good article on the dev center that covers exactly what you're asking:

- [HTML, CSS, and JavaScript features and differences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465380.aspx)

See especially the "Differences" section which details `alert`, `prompt`, `open`, etc., and dynamic features like `document.write`, `inner/outerHTML`, etc.

Also definitely take the time to read the "Local and web context pages" section to understand why & when features may or may not function.  Here's a summary of how features are affected by context:

- [Features and restrictions by context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465373.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have tried this page before: [Metro App using HTML/JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229576.aspx). I believe you will be able to find all the JS-related function calls from here.

From what I see, the DOM looks the same and the `document.write()` function is indeed supported, as you can see from [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh466249.aspx). However, it does has a special mention:

> Remarks
>   Do not use the write method or the writeln method on the current document after the document has finished loading unless you first call the open method, which clears the current document window and erases all variables.
>   Note  When document.write or document.writeln is used in an event handler, you must also use document.close.

Hope that helps.